# Token for Total Flag Count

Tags: 8, theming, tokens, flags

I have created a flag for my comments named HELPFUL. If users find a comment helpful they vote it as such.

The challenge that I have is how do I show the total votes for the flag next to the button? If a comment was voted as helpful 5 times for example, show that next to the helpful button.

If there are no helpful votes for a particular comment show nothing (do not display 0) but only the HELPFUL rate button (flag)

I have tried to add [flag-action:count] and [flag-helpful-count] as the token under the flag setting (/admin/structure/flags/manage/helpful >>edit>> Flag link text) but it does not work.

Looked at COMMENT tokes and I see this available: [comment:flag-helpful-count]
It still won't work. It shows this text [comment:flag-helpful-count] instead of a total number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You try code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = array();
  if($type == 'comment' && !empty($data['comment'])) {

    foreach($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch($name) {
        case 'flag-helpful-count':
          //$comment = \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment::load($data['comment']->get('cid')->value);
          //$count_flag = \Drupal::service('flag.count')->getEntityFlagCounts($comment);
          $replacements[$original] = 10;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}

function mymodule_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  $token_service = \Drupal::token();
  $token_count_flag = $token_service->replace('[comment:flag-helpful-count]', array('comment' =>
    $variables['elements']['#entity']));

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Which file is this supposed to go in?

Comment: I think you will need it

Comment: I have a custom theme. I am not sure which file to paste the code you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: It executes in the custom module